# Authentication options for API serving website and mobile app

Tags: api, authentication, mobile, oauth, hmac

As part of a wider learning process, I am looking to build a website and mobile application with a common api for data storage and retrieval (think of it as a simple cms). The mobile app will have additional functionality for things like offline storage (of draft articles for example if offline) and accessing media/camera etc. There will be a public facing home page with a secure area for each member to create/modify their own content.

I have done a lot of reading around but would like some feedback on a recommended architecture for this in terms of how to handle authentication (I am comfortable with building the app and website and api itself). Let's say also that at some point in the future I might like to open the api up to third parties. There are a whole host of options out there but I can't seem to find any decent diagrams representing the flows. Pros and cons for this scenario and links to diagrams of the below options would be great.

Would rather not require users to login every time they access app (or website come to that) and am worried about having any private keys on mobile app also.

This must be a very common scenario nowadays and am just wondering what experience people have with each of these.

OAuth 1a
OAuth 2
HMAC
Basic with SSL
Apache Shiro
Hosted services such as StormPath
Any other options

It would be nice for end users to be able to login with their social accounts (Twitter, Facebook et al) as well as being able to create an account with the website/app also.